# Add Event to element added using ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, event-handling

So I am having this little problem, I will start by writing the code and explaining what I tried to achieve.

Here is a part of my jsp file :

```
 <form method="POST">
       <input type="hidden" value="5" class="val" >
       <input type="submit" class="button2"> 
 </form>
 <div id="result"></div>
```

I want that when I click my button with the class name 'button2', I get the value in my hidden input and send it to my servlet.

I used jQuery to do that, and here is my javascript code :

```
$(".button2").click(function(){
    var val = $(".val").val()
    $.ajax({
       type:"POST",
       url:"controllerServlet",
       data:{val:val},
       success:function(result){
          $("#result").html(result)
       }
   })
   // this method will be explained after
   affectation()
 })
```

Now, I get the value in my controller and use it to get data from the database and store my data in ArrayList and send it to my `jsp` page again, Here is the code :

```
public class controllerServlet extends HttpServlet {

   doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp){

        if(req.getParameter("val")!=null){
        int val = Integer.parseInt(req.getParameter("val"));
        // getUsersOfGroup return an ArrayList and this method works fine
        ArrayList<User> users = new Service().getUsersOfGroup(val);
        /* contentOfList is a method that return a String - it will be 
           defined */
        String result = Service.contentOfList(users);
        out.print(users); 
        }
   }
}
```

I used the method contentList because I didn't know how to send an ArrayList and get it with jquery.

Here is the definition of the method in my class Service :

```
public static String contentList(ArrayList<User> users){
    String data = "";
    for(User user:users){
         data += "<div class=\"res\"><p class=\"name\">"+user.getName()+"</p><button class=\"data\">data</button></div>";
    }
    return data;
}
```

In my inspector I can see that everything is fine until now and that is what I see :

```
 <form method="POST">
   <input type="hidden" value="5" class="val" >
   <input type="submit" class="button2"> 
 </form>
 <div id="result">
     <div class="res">
         <p class="name">Dominic</p><button class="data">data</button>
     </div>
     <div class="res">
         <p class="name">Julien</p><button class="data">data</button>
     </div>
     <div class="res">
         <p class="name">Yanick</p><button class="data">data</button>
     </div>
</div>
```

Now I want that when I click my button data the name of User chosen will be shown in an alert and here is my code :

```
function affectation(){
   var lg = $(".res").length
   for(var i=0; i<lg; i++){
       $(".res:eq("+i+")").find(".data").click(function(){
             alert($(".res:eq("+i+")").find(".name").text())
       })
}
```

But it seems like I didn't add any event to my added elements.

And How can I send an ArrayList from my controller to `jsp` without refreshing my page?

Any Help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use event delegation here. As result container is already there, you could attach click event handler on it and target element will give you clicked button element.

```
$('#result').on('click', 'button.data', (e) => {
   const nameElement = $(e.target).siblings('.name');
   alert(nameElement.text());
});
```

Example with dynamic content - https://jsfiddle.net/56fe6cfs/1/